# Finding right Android touchscreen driver file

Tags: android, kernel, driver, touchscreen

My goal is to add a single printk command to one of the driver files for my phone's touchscreen. I would like to run this printk command everytime the screen recieves touch input. I found the list of touchscreen driver files shown below. I'm just hoping someone with some experience might be able to point me to the correct file to place this printk command.

```
ad7877.c       atmel_224e.c    cy8ctmg110_ts.c  gunze.c           intel-mid-touch.c
max11801_ts.c  pcap_ts.c       touchit213.c     ucb1400_ts.c      wm9712.c  
ad7879.c       atmel_mxt_ts.c  da9034-ts.c      h3600_ts_input.c  jornada720_ts.c
mc13783_ts.c   penmount.c      touchright.c     usbtouchscreen.c  wm9713.c
ad7879.h       atmel_tsadcc.c  dynapro.c        hampshire.c       Kconfig 
mcs5000_ts.c   s3c2410_ts.c    touchwin.c       w90p910_ts.c      wm97xx-core.c
ad7879-i2c.c   atmel-wm97xx.c  eeti_ts.c        hp680_ts_input.c  lpc32xx_ts.c  
migor_ts.c     st1232.c        tps6507x-ts.c    wacom_w8001.c     zylonite-wm97xx.c
ad7879-spi.c   bu21013_ts.c    elo.c            htcpen.c          mainstone-wm97xx.c
mk712.c        stmpe-ts.c      tsc2005.c        wm831x-ts.c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First Check the Driver file by using the following command on terminal:
     $logcat | grep EventHub 
You will find all the input devices (Including your touch driver) in the prints.

Go to that file and add the print command in interrupt handler.

Comment: Can you tell me similar command to check which display lcd driver has been loaded and is being used at runtime ?

Comment: It works but the command should be run just after restarting device on a non rooted device.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the `getevent` command in a shell on the Android device. The touchscreen should be listed, and the name should be the driver being used.

Here's what came up on my phone:

```
add device 7: /dev/input/event1
  name:     "synaptics_dsx"
```

This means my phone uses the `synaptics_dsx` touchscreen driver.