# Finding right Android touchscreen driver file from the kernel

Tags: android, linux, kernel, driver, touchscreen

User user2655110 had asked about the same question before.
([Finding right Android touchscreen driver file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058758/finding-right-android-touchscreen-driver-file))
One of the answers for that question states that to "Check the Driver file by using the following command on terminal: $logcat | grep EventHub"
Please if any one can explain on which terminal to use that command (logcat | grep EventHub) It will be helpful. 
Is it on phone's terminal? 
please give some directions.
As the user user2655110 my goal is also to add a single printk command to one of the driver files for my phone's touchscreen.

Thanks

Comment: explain your question or hyperlink to previous question.

Comment: You can use `logcat` either on your device's `shell` or [`adb`'s](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) one.

Answer (score 0):

The driver file name which is out putted in logact|grep eventhub is not the same name in the source code. Touch screen controller that Nexus 5 uses is Synaptics. 
The print comand can be added in synaptics file.