# logcat | grep EventHub does not display anyhting

Tags: android, linux, kernel, driver, touchscreen

My goal is to add a single printk command to one of the driver files for my phone's touchscreen.
I found from [Finding right Android touchscreen driver file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058758/finding-right-android-touchscreen-driver-file) to use that command to get driver info.
I used command prompt of my pc.
to view logcat output I did adb logcat.
I then I had the command logcat | grep EventHub, But It does not display anything.
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

It would display all the drivers running in the device. This command should runned just after restarting the device.
Also if device is rooted, then the command could be runned any time.